# How to grab a jquery-generated form field value where the id includes a dynamically generated int --using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, oop, model-view-controller

So I'm working on an object-oriented PHP website that uses the MVC model. In my view, I have the following code that is generating a form:

```
    //Handle add custom module button click

      $('.custom-btn').click(function() {

    var id = $('.custom-fieldset').length + 1;
    var fieldset = '<fieldset style="display: none;" id="custom_module_fieldset_'+id+'" class="custom-fieldset fancy"><legend>Title goes here</legend><label 

    id="label_custom_edit_title_'+id+'" for="custom_edit_title_'+id+'">
    <span>Edit title:</span><input id="custom_edit_title_'+id+'" type="text" name="custom_edit_title_'+id+'" value=""></label><label id="custom_label_edit_desc_'+id+'" for="custom_edit_desc_'+id+'"><span>Edit description:</span><textarea id="custom_edit_desc_'+id+'" name="custom_edit_desc_'+id+'" rows="5"></textarea></label><input id="custom_to_default_'+id+'" type="button" name="custom_to_default_'+id+'" class="custom-confirm-btn" value="Delete this Custom Module"></fieldset>';

    $('#add_custom_module').before(fieldset);
    $('#custom_module_fieldset_'+id).fadeIn();

    return false;
  });
```

I need to insert these values into the db, which means getting them back to the controller page. I'm trying to do this:

```
$ctt = 'custom_edit_title'.$id; 
$ctd = 'custom_edit_desc'.$id; 
$customTextTitle = $_POST[$ctt]; 
$customTextDescription = $_POST[$ctd];
```

I've tried without single quotes, and messed around a bit, but ultimately I'm not sure how to handle the +id+ in the fieldnames in the jquery-generated form. How do I then set that part of it in the php variable?

TO SUMMARIZE::: How do I grab the form field in jquery and feed it back to the controller written in PHP?

Comment: dont you need to `post` the form and catch the values in the controller??

Comment: Your javascript is running client-side - the php is interepreted before it's sent to the client. If you want those variables server-side, you'll have to either send them back through form submission or use ajax. What it is you're trying to do with them?

Comment: The `id` variable in  javascript is totally separate from the PHP variables. Where is `$id` coming from in the PHP code?

Comment: I did have this set as a post originally...you're probably right 3nigma.

Comment: I do understand that js / jquery is client side and that you can use php var's in jquery because they get interpreted first. but we're going the other direction here, and generating a form in jquery in the view that then needs to be passed back to the controller as php variables.

Comment: I know the id in php is totally separate...that's the whole point of this question. if I'm trying to grab a form field that has a dynamically generated id var in it, how the heck do I set that to a php variable??

Comment: make a GET or POST request via a form or AJAX.

Comment: I don't think that's a valid option as this form is mostly generated using a form class written in php. This one little piece is generated in jquery...

Comment: The solution ended up being looping through the POST (which did have what it needed) and checking for a string within a string using stristr to look for the values coming from the jquery above. Then it gets sent to either the updating function or the insert function depending on some additional logic. Thanks everyone for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a short PHP script to insert the data into the database, or, if you are using MVC, write a method inside your controller.

Then use any of jquery's $.ajax methods to send the jquery generated variables to the appropriate method inside your controller, which will then write to the database (and send back any appropriate information, if you want to go that far)